# Does Android have ssp(Secure simple pairing) Debug mode?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have Galaxy Nexus and I want to sniff packets between phone and a bluetooth device. I found that ssp(secure simple pairing) has debug mode, but I couldn't find how to turn on the debug mode on Galaxy Nexus. Please someone help me to find it.

Comment: Just curious to know, is your other bluetooth device is also 2.1 ..if its 2.0 or older version no need to put device in sniff mode

Comment: @ashish Sure, they are also 2.1.